# Chrome webRequest onBeforeRequest won't redirect after receiving function return

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So basically I'm making some kind of phish website detector.
What my program does is:

1. Send the URL to a Flask backend in localhost
2. Wait for the backend to process the URL (I had to make XHR synchronous otherwise it will just redirect before the result is received)
3. Backend send the result (0 = legitimate, 1 = phishy) back to the extension
4. The extension redirects based on the result. If 0, redirects back to the URL. If 1, redirects to a local page `blocked.html`

The problem lies in the redirection. It just redirects back to the URL, no matter what the result is.

Code: 
**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Phishing Site Detector",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": true
    },

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "blocked.html"
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
function checkurl(url){
    console.log("checking URL..");
    console.log(url);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("response received!");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            return xhr.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/"+url, false); 
    xhr.send(); 
};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details){
        var res = checkurl(details.url);
        if(res == "0"){
            console.log("redirecting back..");
            return { redirectUrl: details.url };
        }else if(res == "1"){
            console.log("blocked!");
            return { redirectUrl: "chrome-extension://njfcgcmoahjhhbggmapgphfapmedmjhj/blocked.html" };
        }
    },
    {
        urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        types: ["main_frame"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkurl() function actually doesn't return anything; it just logs the results. BTW, isn't that possible to use async listener (the one that returns a Promise resolving with BlockingResponse, as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest))?

Comment: @raina77ow I haven't tried it yet. But for now the accepted answer works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onBeforeRequest can't be async in chrome extensions so your code is almost there, but when using the deprecated synchronous XHR, its `send` waits for the response so instead of xhr.onreadystatechange event you simply access the response right away:

```js
function checkurl(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/' + url, false); // synchronous
  xhr.send();
  return xhr.responseText;
}
```